# Modifying nth li in a list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying something very basic, but I just can't figure out why this won't work.
I can get information on the object using [i] but I can't change data this way?

```
    // Make all the li's invisible
$('div#rotator ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

// Calculate a random number between 1 and 3
var randnr = Math.floor((1-4)*Math.random()) + 4;

for(var i = 0; i < $('#rotator ul li').length; i++) {

            // Make the i element appear
    $('#rotator ul li')[i].css({opacity: 1.0});
}
```

Comment: What's the `for` loop for? With what you currently have, just `$('#rotator ul li').css({opacity: 1.0});` replacing the entire loop would work...

Comment: The loop was leftover code from before. I decided to keep it in the test, to loop through the elements as a test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery objects are array-like objects that can be used as an array of raw DOM elements.
Therefore, `$(...)[i]` gets the i'th *raw DOM element*, not a jQuery object containing it.

To get a jQuery object containing the i'th element, call the [`.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), like this:

```
$('#rotator ul li').eq(i).css({opacity: 1.0});
```

You can also use the [`:eq` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
$('#rotator ul li:eq(i)').css({opacity: 1.0});
```

---

However, you don't need a loop at all; you can hide all of the elements at once:

```
$('div#rotator ul li').css({opacity: 1.0});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this problem because when you use array indices you get a DOM element and [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/) is a method on a jQuery object. So you can do:

```
$($("#rotator ul li")[i]).css("opacity", 1.0);
```

Of course that's awkward so you can use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$("#rotator ul li").eq(i).css("opacity", 1.0);
```

But you're doing that change in all elements in the set so a simpler solution than a loop is to simply do:

```
$("#rotator ul li").css("opacity", 1.0);
```

That will apply the CSS to all elements in the jQuery object.